# Searching an image in PHP using part of a filename

Tags: php, image, substring

I am using the code below to search a directory using PHP for around 11 JPG image files

```
        $dbImage=$row["pref"];
        $imageName=$dbImage;
        $str2 = substr($imageName, -4);
        $extension=".jpg";
        $fileName=$str2.$extension;
        echo "<img src='Images/proppics/$filename'>";
```

However this does not seem to work and an empty box is displayed.

The files are named as follows,

```
AT-1410f1654.jpg
AT-1410_1655.jpg
AT-1410_1656.jpg
AT-1410_1657.jpg
AT-1410_1658.jpg
AT-1410_1659.jpg
```

As you can notice the first image has 7 characters followed by the letter f. The remaining images are separated by _. What I need to perform is display ALL the images (first 7 characters only) in a slideshow. And the image which is separated with f should be displayed on the top of the page. Any ideas how to perform this task, and also the reason for the previous coding error

Full Code

```
// rows to return
$limit=10; 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("movedb") or die("Unable to select database");
$query="select * FROM properties where `name`='Beata Grande 1' & `catergory`='Villas'& `price`=202800 & `area`='Arenas'& `bedrooms`=2 & `region`='Axarquia'";
$numresults=mysql_query($query,$con);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
echo "<center>";
echo "<p>You searched for: &quot;" . $properties . "&quot;</p>";
echo "<form name=payment action='properties_details.php'>";
echo "Results <br>";
  while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $pid=$row['pref'];
    // Retrieve the balance database fields

      echo "<p>Property ID &nbsp".$pid;
      echo "<br> <p> Name &nbsp";
      echo $row["name"];
      echo "<br>  Properties &nbsp";
      echo $row["catergory"];
      echo "<br> Description &nbsp";
    // Print results
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<input type=submit name=btnbuy value=MoreDetails> ";
```

Comment: Please post the code where you are retrieving the files.

Comment: Please check the code attached

Comment: After the database values were read, the previous code to read the image files comes

Comment: Can you provide more debug information. Do `var_dump($row)` and `var_dump($fileName)` just to see if they really have values inside them

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are **[case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)** in PHP.

Your variable is called `$fileName`, but you are using it in the `echo` statement as `$filename`.

Replace

```
echo "<img src='Images/proppics/$filename'>";
```

with

```
echo "<img src='Images/proppics/$fileName'>"; // Capital 'N'
```